# value is not passing in <a> tag in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

Html Template

```
<template  for:each={LocationKeyData} for:item="Loc">
                            <button key={Loc.Id} value={Loc.Id} onclick={AuditcardBUtton}></button>
                                <a key={Loc.Id}  value={Loc.Id} onclick={AuditcardBUtton}>
                                    <ul class="card">
                                        <li>
                                           {Loc.Name__c}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </a>

                        </template>
```

JS

```
AuditcardBUtton(event){
            console.log('event.target.Value'+event.target.value);
}
```

So when i click on button id is passing into value and it shows the Id but if i click on "a" tag value is showing undefined 
I jus want to pass my Id into "a" How i can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tag doesn't have a value attribute. You need to use `data-` attribute like this. Also, make sure that `Loc` is not null

```
<a key={Loc.Id}  data-value={Loc.Id} onclick={AuditcardBUtton}>
    <ul class="card">
        <li>
           {Loc.Name__c}
        </li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

You can access data attributes like this.

```
AuditcardBUtton(event) {
    console.log('Value = ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.value);
}
```

[Playground Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/SJsYR7gs1/3/edit)

Comment: using dataset attributes is the way however event.preventDefault() is not required here.